# Python dict, extracting values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having trouble to query my database maybe someone could give me a hand. 
I am using a django application so I guess Sqlite3 >> and the output I would like to get is the score value

```
b = Answer.objects.get(id = 23)
```

which give me an output of :

```
<Answer: Answer to questionID '4' : AnswerID '23'>
```

when I do :

```
b.values
```

I get a dict in the form :

```
 ['{
    "1)Long descriptive text":Score,
    "2)Long descriptive text":Score,
    "3)Long descriptive text":Score,
    "4)Long descriptive text":Score
    }']
```

with score beeing an Integer from 0 to 100 so for example "Long descriptive text":85

I need to extract the score using a query but I can't manage to do it
Normaly for a Dict[key:value] I would do a Dict[key] but here I do not know how to do it

could you give me a hand 
Thx you very much

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include what kind of DB you are using, and what framework you are using to access the DB? Is `Answer` a database table, or a class you wrote?

Comment: Also can put here what output do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your question is confusing somehow. I feel you are feeding us much more information than we need to know.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: What you posted below "I get a dict in the form :" is NOT a dict - it looks like a list whose single element is a string representation of either a python dict or, more probably, a jsonified python dict. Now without seeing your model's code, no one can really help here.

Answer (score 2):

This looks suspiciously like Django If so:

so `b = Answer.objects.get(id = 23)` is not truely that - what you are seeing is the *str* function of the Answer when you print it off. because you used `.get` rather then a `.filter` you get the object rather then a QuerySet (which you can think of as being a list).

Basically, I suspect you shouldn't be using values, but accessing the data... something like

```
b = Answer.objects.get(id=..)
b.score
```

or if you wanted to loop over other answers:

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(...)
for a in answers:
    a.score
```

for what the `.score` is, look in your models.py file - look what parameters is has (things looking like `score = models.IntegerField()` etc, then you would use a.score)

Comment: Hi Jmons, ok I got the diff between filter and get, but the thing is that the attribute in questiion is body so a.body and that a.body is a dict coresponding to what I wrote in my post : ['{
    "1)Long descriptive text":Score,
    "2)Long descriptive text":Score,
    "3)Long descriptive text":Score,
    "4)Long descriptive text":Score
    }'] with score beiing an integer and I need to extract that valeu

Comment: I think you need to paste your model code at this point. Your "body" What you've got there looks like an array (`[`) with a single element (going from the `'` to the end `'`, I.e. have you inserted a dictinary into a string... previously did you do foo.body = somedict, which would have cast to a str.. If this is the case, you need to go back and not do that (because thats not how to serialise python dcits) and do something like json.dumps(foo) into the "body" (or even better on new django, look at using the jsonfield!)... that way your 'body' would be a dict on return.